# How to see schematic error in Altium?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, schematics, altium

[image: RED colour line is schematic error]

In the Altium PCB view, we can check this kind of error with ALT+Right Click Twice

But in the Altium Schematic view, I am not able to do the same. Is there any other shortcut to this?

Comment: I think it's a real time thing already. Altium marks the unconnected pins, mismatched input/output nets etc automatically. You can also compile the schematic or the project to see a list of warnings and errors.

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to hover the object with your mouse cursor. The resulting tooltip contains information about the error, as in this example:

[image: Altium schematic view, tooltip with error information]